# TypeScript: Build: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: compiler-errors, bing-maps, typescript1.5

I have this code (trimmed):

```
class cSubjectSite  {

    collectionHomeMarker: Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection;

    showAddressMarker() {
        var opts: Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollectionOptions = { 
            zIndex: zIndex_HomeMarker, bubble: true, visible: true 
        };
    }
    // Compiler error on this line:
    this.collectionHomeMarker = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection(opts);
}
```

This looks good to me. Here from the declaration Microsoft.Maps.d.ts:

```
export interface EntityCollectionOptions {
    bubble?: boolean;
    visible?: boolean;
    zIndex?: number;
}

export class EntityCollection implements Entity {
    EntityCollection(options?: EntityCollectionOptions);
    // Etc.
```

There is also a second declaration file I am using (Microsoft.Maps.AdvancedShapes.d.ts) for extended features which has another definition for EntityCollection:

```
export class EntityCollection implements Entity {
    constructor(options?: EntityCollectionOptions);
```

It looks like the two def files are targeting different ts versions (different constructor syntax)? I do not know enough about def files to say.

I am using VS 2013 with ts 1.5. I made sure my path variable and my proj file were both referencing v1.5. I obtained my Bing Maps def files from Nuget.

I am new to typescript so I may be missing something fundamental.

- Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like a bad declaration. I changed the Microsoft.Maps.d.ts EntityCollection declaration to:

```
export class EntityCollection implements Entity {
    constructor(options?: EntityCollectionOptions);
```

This apparently is the correct syntax for the version of TS I am using (1.5).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft never released a TypeScript library for Bing Maps. The one you found on Nuget must be a wrapper created by someone. Not sure who well it is wrapped. In the Bing Maps API there is no Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollectionOptions class, this is just a placeholder name where you put in an object that has the options. For example:

```
var opts = { visible: true };
var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection(opts);
```

Comment: The def file is from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). There is no Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollectionOptions but there is a [Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollectionOptions object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427614.aspx) and thus the def file includes it for typing purposes. I do not know how well it is wrapped either which is why I included the snippets from the def file so someone can see if there is something wrong there.